# g-brief2 resize address window

Tags: line-breaking, letters

I want to send a `g-brief2` based letter with a very long address that does not fit the address window. The address is automatically hyphenated, which looks strange in this particular case.

Does anybody know how I can make the address window bigger without changing the rest of the structure of `g-brief2`?

MWE:

```
%% LyX 2.0.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,german]{g-brief2}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
 \newcommand{\LyxGruss}[1]
   { \Gruss{#1}{0.5cm} }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\fenstermarken % prints address window marks
\faltmarken % prints folding marks
%\lochermarke % prints puncher marks 
\trennlinien % prints striplines
%\unserzeichen % prints "our ref" instead of "my ref"



\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}


\Adresse{
{\large Prof. Dr. X Y}\\
{\large Humongously long address. Seriously, it's that long!}\\
}


\Datum{\today}


\Betreff{Address shortening}


\Anrede{Dear Prof Y,}


\LyxGruss{Best regards,}


\Unterschrift{j}

\begin{g-brief}
Please shorten your address!
\end{g-brief}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using LyX, I assume you're after a Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble solution. Original output:

[image]

1. You can either set the address using `\raggedright` by adding the following to your LaTeX Preamble:

   ```
   \def\Adresse#1{\def\adresse{\raggedright#1}}
   ```

   This allows content within the `\Adresse` field to wrap without hyphenation.

   [image]
2. You can stretch the `3in` width `\parbox` that holds the address to (say) `6in`:

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch

   \def\fenstermerken@{%
         \put(-9,-18.15){\line( 1, 0){1}} \put(-9,-18.15){\line( 0,-1){1}}%
         \put(126,-18.15){\line(-1, 0){1}} \put(126,-18.15){\line( 0,-1){1}}%
         \put(-9,-61.00){\line( 1, 0){1}} \put(-9,-61.00){\line( 0, 1){1}}%
         \put(126,-61.00){\line(-1, 0){1}} \put(126,-61.00){\line( 0, 1){1}}%
   }
   % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
   \patchcmd{\ps@firstpage}{3in}{6in}{}{}% Adjust width of address box
   \patchcmd{\ps@firstpage}{{85}}{{135}}{}{}% Increase horizontal rule
   \patchcmd{\ps@firstpage}{\iffenstermarken}{\fenstermerken@\fenstermarkenfalse\iffenstermarken}{}{}% Top/bottom right corners of address box
   ```

   The above [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patches does 3 things:

   - Increase the width of the `\parbox`;
   - Increase the horizontal rule above the address; and
   - Move the right-hand top/bottom *fenster marken*.

   [image]

   For something shorter than `6in`, you'll have to fiddle with the numbers `135` and (`126` in `\fenstermarken@`, or 9 less than whatever you choose for `135`)

---

[`g-brief2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/g-brief) is not that flexible.